# How to set background color on sharepoint 2010 site using html?

Tags: html

I have been trying to change the background color of my SP 2010 site using the HTML editor feature. However whenever I attempt to change the background via code, everytime I click OK after editing the HTML source, nothing happens and when I check the code I edited, the color edit gets removed. I am currently trying to put this into the HTML source editor with no success:

```
    <style type="text/css">
    .ms-bodyareaframe {
    background-color: <#D8D8D8>;
    }
    </style>
```

Help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try removing the brackets around the `background-color` value. It should look like:

```
<style type="text/css">
.ms-bodyareaframe {
    background-color: #D8D8D8;
}
</style>
```

If that doesn't work, try adding `#d8d8d8 !important`

Comment: Thanks, that was a silly mistake. The color was changed, but there is still white space around images I've uploaded. Is there anyway to fill in the white space around images?

Comment: @user3621543 ... more than likely you don't have a transparent background in your images. Try using a different image format which supports transparency.